# How to add a <br /> to an iframe after a certain length

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a br tag to my iframe after like 50 characters but don't know why my codes come short. I want to begin a new line after a certain width.

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <iframe frameborder="0" name="textEditor" id="textEditor" style="width:500px; 
  height:80px;border:2px solid #CCC;border-radius:20px;overflow:auto;"> 
</iframe>
</tr>
</table>
```

JQ

```
document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.close();
var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
edit.focus();

var gyt=$("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html().match(/.{1,50}/g);
if($("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html().match(/.{1,50}/g)>=0){
var bod = $("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html();
$("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html(bod+"<br>");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it happens to be this small piece of code that I missed.

```
textEditor.document.body.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
```

It will wrap the characters of the iframe according to its width.
Simple when you know it but hard when you don't know it.